# How do I flip a pose along the y instead of the x axis?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, mirror, transform-orientation

I am trying to flip (or would mirror be the right word?) a rigged character pose along the y axis instead of the x. I understand for normal walk cycles etc you only really need to flip along the x. But I have a character on a longboard. In-game it is possible to turn the board by 180 degrees. The stance of the character is then supposed to go from "regular" to "goofy" (these terms describe poses standing on a skateboard or snbowboard, "regular" is facing your body right, left foot in front and "goofy" is facing your body left and right foot in the front in relation to the forward position of the board).

So, when the character slides/turns the board 180 degrees in-game the part of the board that was front is now the back and the character turns his head, torso, as well as the orientation of his feet, without changing the actual stance (position) of the feet. Basically what was backwards is now forwards, since he turned the board by 180 degrees.

Pic 1 shows my original stance and pic 3 is (obviously) what happens when I copy/paste the flipped pose. What I need is an option to flip it so it's like Pic 2 (I quickly did the Pic 2 pose manually to show what I mean). And obviously I could do this by hand and make a "goofy" alternative to every "regular" stance. But I don't think this is a very good process from a technical aspect since I do want the poses to basically be the same, just flipped. Not to mention all the extra time wasted in manually re-doing every pose in it's flipped version...

I hope this makes sense and is not a stupid or obvious question. Also hope my explanation wasn't too convoluted... Thanks in advance!

[image: reference character poses]

EDIT: side question, I started this post with a "hello", which got deleted for some reason, anyone know what's up with that?

Comment: For the 'hello', read these guidelines: [Expected Behavior](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)

Comment: It seems to me that what you're looking for is the already established Pic 3 pose, plus  a 180 degrees rotation of the root bone on Z axis.

Comment: @joshsanfelici you're absolutely right! I had tried something similar but it resulted in weird behavior. I probably had messed something up in regards to the local/global/pivot/cursor settings yesterday. Whatever it was, doing exactly what you suggested worked like a charm!

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann fair enough, got it!